# Why where clause compares date vs. timestamp differently then case-when clause?

Tags: date, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause, case-when

The condition in the when clause  containing comparision of TIMESTAMP and its trunc() version is apparently evaluated differently than when it is in the where clause.

I am working in Oracle SQL developers. I have a table which has timestamp(6) attribute. I was told that the timestamp attribute has the time dimension always empty (00:00:00,000000). I wanted to check this and I got to interesting problem.
When I use where clause

```
Select * from CUSTOMER_DATA 
where trunc(DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE) <> DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE
```

I get indeed zero rows.

But when I want to see the attributes as truncated, I use Case-when clause

```
CASE WHEN trunc(DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE) = DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE then
          trunc(DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE) 
     else DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE 
end 
from CUSTOMER_DATA
```

I get output in the form of timestamp, i.e. as if condition was false.

Here is some sample table/data:

```
   create table CUSTOMER_DATA(
DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE TIMESTAMP(6),
Another_text VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
)
--select * from customer_data;
Insert into customer_data values(TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-04-15 00:00:00,000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF6'),'Not important');
select
CASE WHEN trunc(DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE) = DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE then
          trunc(DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE) 
     else DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE 
end 
from CUSTOMER_DATA;
select trunc(DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE) from customer_data
where DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE=trunc(DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE);
```

My question is, why this comparison works in the where clause but doesn't work in the Case-when clause?

Comment: Could you provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, please?

Comment: I'm not sure that you came to the right conclusion, `DAT_CUSTOMER_SINCE` can appear truncated because of the date format in your SQL tool (SQL developer in your example). If you don't have the "hh:mi:ss" precision in it `trunc(dat_customer_since)` and `dat_customer_since` will give you the same displayed result.
You can use e.g. `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'` to change it

Comment: @Littlefoot I have added some sample as you have asked for, the problem is present also in this sample even though original data I cannot reveal.
R.Du the problem is, as you can see in added code, that when I select trunc(timestamp) directly (outside being part of case statement), I get only date part, but when it is in the case statement as the part which should be evaluated, I get the whole timestamp. It is possible that result of the case statement can be only in one format and hence the one longer from 2 branches of the case statement is chosen...

Comment: Thank you, Jozef. All I can say is that the result got matches what you've said, but I don't know the reason.

Comment: @It has probably something to do with that case showing always the longest format from possible options.